# Content of div 'sliding' under div above it

Tags: html, css, parallax, responsive

Making a portfolio, I have a very multi-layered parallax homepage and an about section below it. Trying to set it up for one page scrolling so I'm using vh, but for some reason this div just slides under the home page when being resized to the point where the height is very small. It appears as though the home page doesn't appear to push to be below it, as if it has an offset or something. Tried using clear under first div, doesn't work. Here is what it looks like: http://puu.sh/sL8Km/4cf16e2ff7.jpg
I'm assuming it's something to do with the css of the parallax, which looks like this: http://puu.sh/sL8Bb/31cca57cef.png
All of the layers of parallax look like #parabg, #scene and #home are wrappers. Any ideas? Thank you!

Comment: Please provide the code.

Answer (score 0):

The miracle of finding out the problem just after you post the question. If whoever's reading this is also using a very complicated parallax and tried to follow parallax.js' poor documentation, don't use padding-top! I'll make a codepen in a bit for anyone that wants to do a fully responsive multi-layered parallax.

```
#parabg {
background: url(../assets/parallaximages/home/bg2.png) no-repeat 50%;
background-size: cover;
/*    padding-top: 52%; */
width:110%;
height: 100vh;
margin-left:-5%;
```